# Uploading image to the cloudinary using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, cloudinary

I tried to follow the tutorial, but I did not get any idea. Though, please can anyone provide the full example.

Comment: did you check this documentation http://cloudinary.com/documentation/jquery_image_upload  ??

Comment: Yes I tried to understand but did not get any idea.

Comment: Please elaborate on what's your exact issue. "Don't get an idea" is too broad an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Cloudinary's documentation is dispersed over a few pages. It takes a bit of searching to piece together the complete plugin functionality.

For starters, go through the following links:

1. http://cloudinary.com/documentation/jquery_image_upload
2. http://cloudinary.com/blog/direct_image_uploads_from_the_browser_to_the_cloud_with_jquery
3. http://cloudinary.com/documentation/jquery_integration

Check out the second link. I tried this and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Note that with the jQuery you can perform both [unsigned-uploads](http://cloudinary.com/blog/direct_upload_made_easy_from_browser_or_mobile_app_to_the_cloud) or signed with a server-side, Cloudinary's docs includes sample projects to the common server-side frameworks which demonstrate both server side and client-side uploads with the jQuery library (both signed and unsigned).
For example, for PHP:
https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_php/tree/master/samples/PhotoAlbum